# How to create new dataframe off of values from a previous dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a sample dataframe:

```
| ID | SampleColumn1| SampleColumn2 | SampleColumn3 | SampleColumn4 |
|:-- |:------------:| ------------ :| ------------  | ------------  |
| 1  |sample Apple  | sample Cherry | sample Lime   | sample Apple  |
| 2  |sample Cherry | sample lemon  | sample Grape  | sample Cherry |
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame based off of this initial dataframe. Should one of several values in a list [Apple, Lime, Cherry, Guava, Pear] be in any of the columns for a row, it would **appear as a 1 in the new dataframe for its column**. I do not wish to get the frequency, just if one of the values of the values from the list are in the dataframe row, then it should be a 1, else it will be a 0. In this case, the output should be:

```
| ID | Apple | Lime | Cherry | Guava | Pear |
| 1  |  1    |  1   |    1   |  0    |   0  |
| 2  |  0    |  0   |    1   |  0    |   0  |
```

Currently I have tried in going about in initially establishing the dataframe by creating the columns based off the list mentioned before (list=[Apple, Lime, Cherry, Guava, Pear]) and then using the find function for a string, transforming a series into a string for each row then using an if condition if the value has returned and equals the column name of the new dataframe. I am getting a logic error in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **stack()** and **pivot_table()**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Apple','Lime','Cherry','Apple'],['Cherry','Lemon','Grape','Cherry']])
df_stack = pd.DataFrame(df.stack()).droplevel(1).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'fruit'})
df_stack['values'] = 1
df_stack.pivot_table(index = 'index',columns=['fruit'], values='values').fillna(0)
```

OP:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with aggregate `max`:

```
f = lambda x: x.replace('sample ','')
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID'), prefix='', prefix_sep='').rename(columns=f)
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1).max())
print (df)
    Apple  Cherry  Grape  Lime  lemon
ID                                   
1       1       1      0     1      0
2       0       1      1     0      1
```